# Library to create videos from pictures and text?

Tags: php, python, video, video-processing

Is there some library to generate a video from pictures and text? Something like animoto.com does but much simplier.

I basically want to set one picture, and fade in and out text over that picture and make a video out of that.

I am looking for something to run from php or python, video format is not so important.

Comment: You really need to be more specific about what you expect the library to do and what you plan to implement yourself.

Comment: I basically want to set one picture, and fade in and out text over that picture and make a video out of that.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider an animated GIF to be a video?  If so use imagemagick!

Comment: mm, this could be a solution, maybe I can find something to convert the gif to some video format. Can imagemagick add text effects like fade in/out?

Comment: I actually kinda posted this as a joke, but you can use ffmpeg and imagemagick together and probably pull this off.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pyffmpeg module at http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/ which ought to be able to do this; I'll see if I can bash together an example.

**Edit:** ok, I take it back. It doesn't look like pyffmpeg is being actively maintained, and I've just about had an aneurysm trying to get the son-of-a-gun to build on Windows (there's a binary download for 2.6, but none for 2.7). Apparently the preferred method is to cross-compile it from Ubuntu (?!) It may be fine if you're on Linux, but on Windows I'm throwing in the towel.